# Problem installing mysql 5 on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.10

In my Ubuntu 10.10, following this [tutorial](http://blog.sudobits.com/2010/10/27/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-10-10/), I don't face step 2. I mean, while installing the packets, I don't face anything related to configuration.

Then, when I run a command, such a

> mysql -u root -p

, I get this error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to
>   local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

As I see in other treads,

> ps aux | grep mysqld

gives me just this output:

> 1000 4508 0.0 0.0 5172 760 pts/0 S+
>   19:53 0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld

As you suggested me:

> aptitude search mysql | grep ^i
>   Gives me:
>
> i A libmysqlclient16                -
>   MySQL database client library
>   i A libqt4-sql-mysql                -
>   Qt 4 MySQL database driver
>   i   mysql-client-core-5.1           -
>   MySQL database core client binaries
>   i A mysql-common                    -
>   MySQL database common files, e.g.
>   /etc/mys i   mysql-server-core-5.1
>   - MySQL database server binaries

What is happening??
Thanks in advance

Comment: This **doesn't** represent a vote to close, but I'd suggest asking this over at [the Ubuntu Stack Exchange site](http://askubuntu.com/), or maybe [the Unix/Linux Stack Exchange site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) for more specific help, where the question is likely more on-topic than SO.

Comment: Yes, I already did it before asking here, but with no succes. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check that mysql is installed:

```
aptitude search mysql | grep ^i
```

If it's not do:

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

This will show the mysql packages that you have installed.

If it is installed, it seems that the sql deamon is not started try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: I edited my question, but I don't really understand what does it mean. Thanks